# Unable to succesfully add to cart via post request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am emulating the requests sent to this website to try add a product to cart - although it is not working as intended and I am not sure why. Here is my series of requests sent.

```
    s = requests.Session()

    payload = {
        "sku": "182418M20400102",
        "serviceType": "product-details",
        "userId": None,
    }

    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
    }
    s.get("https://www.ssense.com/en-ca/mini-shopping-bag") // Initialize cookies
    resp = s.post("https://www.ssense.com/en-ca/api/shopping-bag/182418M20400102", json=payload, headers=headers)
    print(resp.status_code)

    bag = s.get("https://www.ssense.com/en-us/mini-shopping-bag")

    print(bag.json())
```

Console printout is:

```
https://www.ssense.com/en-ca/api/shopping-bag/182418M20400102 // pid in this case
204 // Expected status code
{'quantity': 0, 'token': 'xxxx'} // qty should be 1
```

Not sure why it is not working.

Comment: where is the bag object created? are you hitting the database for updated value?

Comment: Apologies, the `self.bag` was a object hardcoded url string. I'll update it now. It's an endpoint to check our cart.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to do cookie management. this website stores your value in a cookie.
since you are making a post request, the next time you hit a get request, the values are stored in a cookie in the actual website. The web browsers manage our cookies so the bag has the data added. If you hit the same in incognito mode you will not have any data. 
refer http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/ for setting a cookie.[image]

Comment: I assumed that requests would pass on cookies automatically? Hence why I went to the mini shopping bag endpoint first to get cookies.

Comment: Added a picture above for reference. Hope that helps.